# PDO Not Synchronized?

Tags: php, multithreading, asynchronous, pdo

I am getting the idea that when I have a prepared statement with the PDO driver (you first prepare a statement and bind any variables to it and then execute it) that the rest of the PHP code continues to execute before the results of that statement have been returned.

Is that indeed the case? And if so, isn't that a big problem?

Answer (score 3):

> Is that indeed the case?

No, this is not the case